# IDX13510: The Saml2SecurityToken cannot be validated because the Assertion specifies a OneTimeUse

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We are recieving an exception when validating an assertion with a OneTimeUse Condition. We do not see a way to override or change this behavior. Any help?

Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: IDX13510: The Saml2SecurityToken cannot be validated because the Assertion specifies a OneTimeUse condition.Enforcement of the OneTimeUse condition is not supported by default.To customize the enforcement of OneTimeUse condition, extend Saml2SecurityTokenHandler and override ValidateOneTimeUseCondition. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateOneTimeUseCondition(Saml2SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateConditions(Saml2SecurityToken samlToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Tokens.Saml2ResponseSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token, String tokenString, Saml2Response saml2Response, Boolean detectReplayedTokens) at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.ReadClaimsIdentity(String tokenString, Boolean detectReplayedTokens) at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2AuthnResponse.Read(String xml, Boolean validateXmlSignature, Boolean detectReplayedTokens) at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2PostBinding.Read(HttpRequest request, Saml2Request saml2RequestResponse, String messageName, Boolean validateXmlSignature, Boolean detectReplayedTokens) at ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2Binding`1.ReadSamlResponse(HttpRequest request, Saml2Response saml2Response)

We tried exploring the options classes and extending the handler but neither seem viable.

`<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_381479691072dae3061c8eb476d8f638726d827456" IssueInstant="2023-01-04T19:59:55.431Z" Destination="https://p-dv-vm-tee8won:443/Relativity/Identity/98E1EA02C6824DB779469702E3C3A50DF55188D3"><saml:Issuer>https://capriza.github.io/samling/samling.html</saml:Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status><saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_b4062517bccdf96dd61be6ad16374ba6aac7bccca6" IssueInstant="2023-01-04T19:59:55.383Z"><saml:Issuer>https://capriza.github.io/samling/samling.html</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#_b4062517bccdf96dd61be6ad16374ba6aac7bccca6"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>czTc3X2L2jmH8hZmbw8CnVbLGWIOCgWpQhLb6cMIRF4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>NH/nBTI88+D7KqA26IahTsf6bpXqSdBsGf/Bk4gvtJ9NGzfEJ14Pxh9fhYgq47begLqSY61Whoek6CQs908p8Qck37BFtvxR4gsWFULGIbb7ybsEMqajBR0pVDarxcC04bgXTa2nmMs2CO0lwl6lBMAEOQaf/03W8SxLSh2ovPQ=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">redactedemail@relativity.com</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2023-01-04T20:09:55.383Z" Recipient="https://p-dv-vm-tee8won:443/Relativity/Identity/98E1EA02C6824DB779469702E3C3A50DF55188D3"/></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore="2023-01-04T19:59:55.383Z" NotOnOrAfter="2023-01-04T20:09:55.383Z"><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>https://p-dv-vm-tee8won/Relativity</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:OneTimeUse></saml:OneTimeUse></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2023-01-04T19:59:55.383Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2023-01-04T20:09:55.381Z" SessionIndex="_samling_4122095_80192495"><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement></saml:Assertion></samlp:Response>`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have newer herd about this problem I'm afraid.

Please add a decoded SAML 2.0 authn response which the problem.

**** EDITED ****

The SAML 2.0 authn response is rejected because it contains the `OneTimeUse` element.

```
  <saml:OneTimeUse>
  </saml:OneTimeUse>
```

The `OneTimeUse` element is optional in SAML 2.0. But not supported by the ITfoxtec Identity SAML library because the underling Microsoft components do not support it.

You can resolve the problem by asking the IdP to remove the empty `OneTimeUse` element.

Comment: Updated Question with a sample assertion.